# What's the correct way to unit test Pyramid views with a SQLAlchemy DBSession?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, sqlalchemy, pyramid

When writing a Pyramid unit test suite, what is the proper or appropriate way to unit test a view that does a SQLAlchemy call.  Example:

```
def my_view(request):
    DBSession.query(DeclarativeBase).all()
```

Would I use `Mock()` and `patch` to override the scope of `DBSession` to a DummyDB class of the sorts?

Comment: This may be helpful:  http://sontek.net/blog/detail/writing-tests-for-pyramid-and-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, and I'll be blogging/speaking/exampling about this soon.  This is totally new stuff.  Here's a sneak peek:

```
import mock

from sqlalchemy.sql import ClauseElement

class MockSession(mock.MagicMock):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kw):
        kw.setdefault('side_effect', self._side_effect)
        super(MockSession, self).__init__(*arg, **kw)
        self._lookup = {}

    def _side_effect(self, *arg, **kw):
        if self._mock_return_value is not mock.sentinel.DEFAULT:
            return self._mock_return_value
        else:
            return self._generate(*arg, **kw)

    def _get_key(self, arg, kw):
        return tuple(self._hash(a) for a in arg) + \
                tuple((k, self._hash(kw[k])) for k in sorted(kw))

    def _hash(self, arg):
        if isinstance(arg, ClauseElement):
            expr = str(arg.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
            return expr
        else:
            assert hash(arg)
            return arg

    def _generate(self, *arg, **kw):
        key = self._get_key(arg, kw)
        if key in self._lookup:
            return self._lookup[key]
        else:
            self._lookup[key] = ret = MockSession()
            return ret


if __name__ == '__main__':

    from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

    Base = declarative_base()

    class Foo(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'foo'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        x = Column(Integer)
        y = Column(Integer)

    sess = MockSession()

    # write out queries as they would in the code, assign return_value
    sess.query(Foo.x).filter(Foo.x == 5).first.return_value = 5
    sess.query(Foo.x).filter(Foo.x == 2).first.return_value = 2
    sess.query(Foo).filter(Foo.x == 2).filter_by(y=5).all.return_value = [Foo(x=2, y=5)]
    sess.query(Foo).filter(Foo.x == 9).all.return_value = [Foo(x=9, y=1), Foo(x=9, y=2)]

    # those queries are now replayable and will return what was assigned.
    print sess.query(Foo.x).filter(Foo.x == 5).first()
    print sess.query(Foo.x).filter(Foo.x == 2).first()
    print sess.query(Foo).filter(Foo.x == 2).filter_by(y=5).all()
    print sess.query(Foo).filter(Foo.x == 9).all()
```

I've actually assigned this into the global `ScopedSession` within setup/teardown and it works amazingly:

```
from myapp.model import MyScopedSession

def setUp(self):
     MyScopedSession.registry.set(MockSession())

     # set up some queries, we can usually use scoped_session's proxying

     MyScopedSession.query(User).filter_by(id=1).first.return_value = User(id=1)

def tearDown(self):
     MyScopedSession.remove()


def some_test(self):
     # to get at mock methods and accessors, call the scoped_session to get at
     # the registry

     #  ... test some thing

     # test a User was added to the session
     self.assertEquals(
            MyScopedSession().add.mock_calls,
            [mock.call(User(name='someuser'))]
     )
```

Comment: Great examples.  Is this stuff that is not in the current release of SQLalchemy but scoped in?  If so I would likely be able to get away with instantiating my sessionmaker with ``DBSession = MagicMock()`` after importing it, no?

Comment: it's all just Mock code, it only uses one SQLAlchemy import to match up SQL expressions.   As far as how to get DBSession to be what you want it depends on the patterns you're using to create and access sessions in pyramid.

Comment: i tried to find more on your blog and didn't see it, is there more than the sneak peak @zzzeek ?